# Bin counting with hex-like bins in 2D

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I use [numpy's historgram 2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html#numpy.histogram2d) 
to count how many (training) data points lie in one each. For a new point `(x,y)` I can then query how may points are in the same bin as `(x,y)`:

[image]

Is there something similar for "hex" bins like in the matplotlib plots

[image]

where I can fill the bins and then later query how may point are in each bin?

Comment: You can try [Seaborn's jointplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html). E.g. `sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", kind="hex")`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the bin data, but it's not as simple as doing the same operation on a rectangular grid.  The reason is that hex bins do not lend themselves to straightforward two-dimensional indexing.  The function [`hexbin()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin), returns a [`PolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) which has the bin locations accessible through `get_offsets()` and bin values accessible through `get_array()`.  So:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hb = plt.hexbin(...)

bin_xy = hb.get_offsets()
bin_counts = hb.get_array()
```